infinispan console and Reverse-proxy nginx trouble
When using the nginx reverse proxy with the infinispan console (v.13 or v.14), an error like this constantly occurs:
2024/07/22 12:45:26 [error] 28529#28529: *134318 upstream sent "Content-Length" and "Transfer-Encoding" headers at the same time while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.1.179, server: infinispan-dev, request: "GET /console /fonts/RedHatText-Regular.woff2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.0.1:11222/console/fonts/RedHatText-Regular.woff2", host: "infinispan**", referrer: "https://infinispan*/console/app.css

The console itself is slow and does not load all the data
nginx conf:
upstream infinispan {    
     server 10.0.1.194:11222;    
     server 10.0.1.195:11222;    
     server 10.0.1.196:11222;    
}



server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    server_name             infinispan*;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/privkey1.pem;
    client_max_body_size    32m;
    error_page              500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://infinispan;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_connect_timeout 300;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    }
    location = /50x.html {
          root              /var/lib/nginx/html;
    }
}

Could you please tell me where I can look to solve this problem?
I tried changing the proxy configuration, but nothing helps

There is a bug in versions 13 and 14 that prevents normal operation. Fixed in version 15.
